# Simple nested for loop in node, need advice

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have this simple segment of code designed to make for example a 10x10 grid. I've recently switched to node and a bit confused how I would go about making this code run correctly as i'm currently thinking from a synchronous perspective.

Currently all my Y values are assigned straight to 10 without going 1,2,3,4,5 for each X value as I would expect.

```
function createHouse(size){

    var tempGridItem;
    var xpos = 0;
    var ypos = 0;
    randnum = Math.random();

    gridItemArr = [[]];

    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++) {

        tempGridItem = new gridItem();

        xpos++;
        ypos = 0;

        for (var count2 = 0; count2 < size; count2++) {

            // X = 0, Y = 0,1,2,3,4,5...
            // X = 1, Y = 0,1,2,3,4,...
            // And so on

            ypos++;

            tempGridItem.xpos = xpos;
            tempGridItem.ypos = ypos;

            gridItemArr.push(tempGridItem);

        }
    }

    console.log("GRID ITEM ARRYA LENGTH: "+ gridItemArr.length);

}
```

How would I code this to make it run as I would expect, and is there any libraries you guys would suggest / material to read to learn more about how this stuff works.

Thanks!

Current output with size of 10:

```
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS1
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS2
YPOS: 9 , XPOS3
YPOS: 9 , XPOS3
YPOS: 9 , XPOS3
YPOS: 9 , XPOS3
```

etc..

Comment: make use of callbacks for what exactly?

Comment: JavaScript in Node is just as synchronous as JavaScript in the client. Native things like for loops etc. Its Node API's (like `fs` for example) and other library API's that may have asynchronous behavior. Its just JavaScript and the core stuff behaves the same.

Comment: Where have you declared **tempGridItem** and **gridItemArr** and **size** variables?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'm just confused my logic seems correct yet my Y pos never moves from 9, Why is this?

Comment: @Raf i've updated my original question with the results i'm getting, tempGridItem is just an object which stored x, y locations and some other stuff

Comment: You are printing something else. You need to do console.log(gridItemArr) and see what output you get.

Comment: I'm printing like this

for (var counter = 0 ; counter < gridItemArr.length; counter++) {
console.log("YPOS: "+gridItemArr[counter].ypos +" , XPOS"+gridItemArr[counter].xpos)
}

Comment: @does_not_compute see my answer, make the same changes to your code, set size variable to something and then re-run your code.

Comment: Can you replace **gridItemArr = [[]];** with **var gridItemArr = [];** or this **var gridItemArr = new Array([]);** and see what happens. Also show how you are printing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, http://jsfiddle.net/TRR4n/
Node is just JS

```
for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
    var cube = cubes[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
        display("cube[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + cube[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or something even simpler
for (var i in array){
   for(var j in array[i]){//do stuff here}
}